# How to hook up instance methods that have an attribute to Action

Tags: c#

I have a given class that "registers" a string message to an Action:

```
class NetworkCode
    {
        private Dictionary<string, Action<dynamic>> registrations = new Dictionary<string, Action<dynamic>>();

        public void Register(string msg, Action<dynamic> action)
        {
            if (registrations.ContainsKey(msg))
            {
                registrations[msg] += action;
            }
            else
            {
                registrations.Add(msg, action);
            }
        }

        public void OnReceiveMessageTest()
        {
            // simulate the callback from the server

            dynamic args = new ExpandoObject();

            args.Mana = 10;
            args.Path = new List<Point>
            {
                new Point { X = 0, Y = 0 },
                new Point { X = 1, Y = 0 },
                new Point { X = 1, Y = 1 }
            };

            registrations["MOVE_OPPONENT"](args);
        }
    }
```

I have an attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    class NetworkMethodAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Message { get; }
        public NetworkMethodAttribute(string msg)
        {
            Message = msg;
        }
    }
```

Then using that attribute:

```
class OpponentTeam
    {
        private int mana = 0;

        public OpponentTeam()
        {

        }

        [NetworkMethod("MOVE_OPPONENT")]
        private void UpdateMana(dynamic args)
        {
            mana = args.Mana;
        }
    }
```

I create instances of classes that use this attribute myself and I create the NetworkCode class. From these instances how can I find methods on the instance that have this attribute and then have them registered by calling the Register() class?

```
NetworkCode network = new NetworkCode();
OpponentTeam opponentTeam = new OpponentTeam();

// I want to register with the NetworkCode from the opponentTeam instance that specific method that has the attribute
```

Comment: So you need to find a way to: 1. Get a list of methods available on `OpponentTeam` and then 2. Check if any of those methods are decorated with `NetworkMethodAttribute`.

Comment: And 3. register that method for that instance via the NetworkCode Register() function. I'm basically defining callbacks for instances based on the msg string value so when that message comes in from the network it'll call all methods from the instances of the objects I created that have that attribute AND match the msg string value.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand the goal. You want to make sure that each instance of `OpponentTeam` can be notified anytime that `NetworkCode` receives a message from the server. If that is correct I'd go with option A.

**Option A**

This option uses a `delegate` and an `event`. [This article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/delegates-and-events-C-Sharp-net/) goes into more detail about delegates, events, and the handler methods.

*Delegate:*

```
// The delegate defines what method signatures can be attached to an event
public delegate void NetworkMessageReceivedHandler(string message, dynamic args);
```

*NetworkCode:*

```
class NetworkCode
{
    // The multi-cast event that many instances can attach to and be notified
    public event NetworkMessageReceivedHandler NetworkMessageReceived;

    public void OnReceiveMessageTest()
    {
        // simulate the callback from the server

        dynamic args = new ExpandoObject();

        args.Mana = 10;
        args.Path = new List<Point>
        {
            new Point { X = 0, Y = 0 },
            new Point { X = 1, Y = 0 },
            new Point { X = 1, Y = 1 }
        };

        // Check to see if any code has registered for this event
        if (NetworkMessageReceived != null)
        {
            // Assuming "MOVE_OPPONENT" is a message from the server
            NetworkMessageReceived("MOVE_OPPONENT", args);
        }
    }
}
```

*OpponentTeam*

```
class OpponentTeam
{
    private int mana = 0;

    // The event handler for each instance
    public void OnNetworkMessageReceived(string message, dynamic args)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
            case "MOVE_OPPONENT": { UpdateMana(args); } break;
            // TODO: Add additional network messages here.
        }
    }

    private void UpdateMana(dynamic args)
    {
        mana = args.Mana;
    }
}
```

*The Wire Up*

```
NetworkCode network = new NetworkCode();
OpponentTeam opponentTeam = new OpponentTeam();

// This registers the opponent instance's handler of the network message received event
network.NetworkMessageReceived += opponentTeam.OnNetworkMessageReceived;
```

**Option B**

*This option addresses the question more directly by making minimal changes to the provided code but does not achieve what I believe the goal to be.*

I tweaked the network code definition to look like this

```
class NetworkCode
{
    private Dictionary<string, Tuple<OpponentTeam, MethodInfo>> registrations = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<OpponentTeam, MethodInfo>>();

    public void Register(string msg, OpponentTeam team, MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (!registrations.ContainsKey(msg))
        {
            registrations[msg] = new Tuple<OpponentTeam, MethodInfo>(team, method);
        }
    }

    public void OnReceiveMessageTest()
    {
        // simulate the callback from the server

        dynamic args = new ExpandoObject();

        args.Mana = 10;
        args.Path = new List<Point>
        {
            new Point { X = 0, Y = 0 },
            new Point { X = 1, Y = 0 },
            new Point { X = 1, Y = 1 }
        };

        Tuple<OpponentTeam, MethodInfo> registration = registrations["MOVE_OPPONENT"];
        registration.Item2.Invoke(registration.Item1, new[] { args });
    }
}
```

...and then I called it like this...

```
NetworkCode network = new NetworkCode();
OpponentTeam opponentTeam = new OpponentTeam();

// This gets the first method that defines the NetworkMethodAttribute
MethodInfo method = opponentTeam.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetCustomAttribute<NetworkMethodAttribute>() != null);

// This gets the actual attribute for the method found
NetworkMethodAttribute attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute<NetworkMethodAttribute>();

// This calls register using the message defined by the attribute, the instance of opponent team, and the method info for invoking the method
network.Register(attribute.Message, opponentTeam, method);
```